# Deleting multiline variable content from a file

Tags: bash, variables, sed, multiline, pacman-package-manager

I am trying to write a Bash script handling Pacman repositories in /etc/pacman.conf usable within a script without depending on the user interaction required by a text editor.

I am having troubles figuring out the remove-option. How do I delete multiple lines or a paragraph from a file based on the content of a multiline variable?

So I have this multiline variable

```
echo "$repo_query_result"
```

and its content looks for example like this

```
[repo-name]
Server = https://host.domain/$arch
```

or for example like this for a disabled repo

```
#[repo-testing]
#SigLevel = PackageRequired
#Include = ./repo-2-mirrorlist
```

When I try the following command which works with single-line variables

```
sed "/$repo_query_result/d" /etc/pacman.conf
```

I get the following error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated address regex
```

All I could find regarding `sed` or `awk` and multiline variables where solutions on how to delete a single line from the variable. Or when it comes to deleting paragraphs it was always a fixed pattern, e.g. the same start and end word, which is not suitable for my case.

EDIT1: The variable is the result of a function within the script and not set manually or derived from another file. So altering the variable is not an option

```
repo_query()
{
sed "/$name/,/+$/!d" $conff | sed '/^$/,/+$/d'
}
```

```
repo_query_result="$(repo_query | cat /dev/stdin)"
```

Comment: `sed` processes the file one line at a time. It can't match a multi-line regexp.

Comment: ... but if you're using GNU `sed`, you can change what it considers a "line".  The `-z` option will make it expect lines to be separated by null characters instead of newlines.  If the input is a text file then this usually makes it consider the whole file as one line.  You would not then want to execute a `d` command on that line, but you could remove matches by `s`ubstituting empty strings for them.

Comment: The variable as input is fixed unfortunately, see EDIT1.

Comment: Better answer is "don't". This is why modern systems support configuration _directories_, not just configuration _files_, so when you add an extra config segment you put it in its own file and you can remove it be just deleting that file.

Comment: In particular, pacman supports an `Include` directive, and its targets can include wildcards; so one can either have a one-line include directive pointing to an individual file that's trivially deleted (both the include directive and the file being easier to delete on their own), _or_ an include directive with a glob pointing at a directory of files, any entry in that directory being deleted with just a `rm`.

Comment: I know `Include`, it is even in my examples. But you still have to edit `pacman.conf` to use `Include`. And currently, at least to my knowledge, there is no convenient way to manage repositories without a text editor that requires user interaction and cannot be use within a script. Furthermore, if you just delete file `Include` is pointing to, you get errors because the repository is still in the configuration file without a location (server or mirrorlist).

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or make similar edits. Your question should remain strictly a question; the way to mark it as resolved is to accept an answer, which you have already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure bash, using [pattern substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
conf=$(<"in.cf")
echo "${conf/"$repo_query_result"}" >"out.cf"
```

Comment: Like this it doesn't seem to do anything, the conf-file stays the same. But if I leave out `$'\n'` it works.
```conf=$(<"in.cf")```
```echo "${conf/"$repo_query_result"}" >"out.cf"```

Comment: usually, assignments to variables in bash strip the trailing newline. If your variable keeps it, then yes, even simpler to leave out the newline

Comment: this variant will minimise trailing newline changes: `mapfile -d '' conf <"in.cf"; printf '%s' "${conf/"$repo_query_result"}" >"out.cf"`

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function to retrieve the content to be removed
repo_query() {
    sed "/$name/,/+$/!d" "$conff" | sed '/^$/,/+$/d'
}

# Set the name and conff variables as per your requirements
name="repo-1-name"
conff="/etc/pacman.conf"

# Call the function to get the content to be removed
repo_query_result=$(repo_query)

# Create a temporary file
tmp_file=$(mktemp)

# Copy the original file to the temporary file, excluding the lines to be removed
sed "/$repo_query_result/Id" "$conff" > "$tmp_file"

# Overwrite the original file with the temporary file
mv "$tmp_file" "$conff"

# Remove the temporary file
rm "$tmp_file"
```

Comment: error
´sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated address regex
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/tmp.UX1Yphcuxp': No such file or directory´

and the resulting conff is empty

Comment: @herrfleischladen

Change the repo query to awk?

repo_query() {
    awk -v name="$name" '
        $0 ~ "[" name "]" {
            printing = 1
            next
        }
        printing && /^\[/ {
            exit
        }
        printing {
            print
        }
    ' "$conff"
}

Comment: Yours gives me a syntax error.  `awk "/$name/,/^$/" $conff | awk "!/^$/"` produces the same result as `sed "/$name/,/+$/!d" $conff | sed "/^$/,/+$/d"`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v r="$repo_query_result" '
    BEGIN { n=split(r,a,/\n/); s=a[1] }
    s && $0==s { s=0; d=n }
    --d<0
' in.conf >out.conf
```

- pass lines to remove as variable `r`
- split `r` on newlines, store in array `a` (there are `n` parts)
- `a[1]` is first line to remove
- initialise `s` to `a[1]`
- if line exactly matches `a[1]`:

  - clear `s` so we don't look for any more copies
  - set counter `d` to `n` (number of lines to remove)
- `d` starts out as 0 so decrementing will give negative value (until `d` is set)

  - when true, default action (print) happens

Comment: might also work: `awk -v r="$repo_query_result" -v RS= 'n=index($0,r) { $0 = substr($0,1,n-1) substr($0,n+1+length(r)) } 1' in.conf >out.conf`

Comment: `awk -v r="$repo_query_result" -v RS= 'n=index($0,r) { $0 = substr($0,1,n-1) substr($0,n+1+length(r)) } 1' in.conf >out.conf` works too but also deletes every empty line in the rest of the file.

Comment: oops. I only tested on very simple data. better not use that version then. Probably should have been `RS='\0'`